# CS50 Finance : Issue with code for Register

Tags: cs50

I am unable to execute Register. Everytime i try to Register, it moves me to Apology.html even when the credentials are correct. Can anyone please review below excerpt from my application.py and help me resolve this?

```
if request.method == "POST":

        # Ensure username was submitted
        if not request.form.get("username"):
            return apology("must provide username", 400)

        # Ensure password was submitted
        elif not request.form.get("password"):
            return apology("must provide password", 400)

        # Ensure password and confirmation match
        elif not request.form.get("password") == request.form.get("confirmation"):
            return apology("passwords do not match", 400)

        # hash the password and insert a new user in the database
        hash = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))
        new_user_id = db.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES(:username, :hash)",
                                 username=request.form.get("username"),
                                 hash=hash)

        # unique username constraint violated?
        if not new_user_id:
            return apology("username taken", 400)

        # Remember which user has logged in
        session["user_id"] = new_user_id

        # Display a flash message
        flash("Registered!")

        # Redirect user to home page
        return redirect(url_for("index"))

    # User reached route via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

Comment: What does the apology say?

Comment: It says Invalid Username / Password

Comment: I made an error in Register.html. So i am able to load but the Apology page being loaded on blank inputs shows Error 500: Internal Server Error. Please help resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) "Invalid Username / Password" does not come from this route (it comes from login route) make sure the action attribute is correct in register.html. 2) if program gives a 500, edit the traceback info from the flask console into the question.

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus Thanks for the input. Can you please elaborate on the Flask console traceback , how to do it?

Comment: in the terminal where `flask run` is executed, Internal Server Errors will produce a traceback to help you track down and troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: Hi, I could resolve all queries except when existing username is used to register. I am still getting Error 500. In the terminal window error appearing is : RuntimeError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.username. How do I resolve this? I don't find any errors in the code for Register (You can see the code in the question).

Comment: You need to check whether or not the username exists first, for example by executing a query to `SELECT` users with that username and, if the result is greater than 0, return an apology.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `confirm password` has a space in it. If a request is coming via HTML, this may be causing you trouble (as it will have to convert to HTML URL encoding, which is %20 for a space).

Try changing your HTML and your code to use a hyphen, or an underscore, or simply make it one word.

HTH

Comment: I made an error in Register.html. So i am able to load but the Apology page being loaded on blank inputs shows Error 500: Internal Server Error. Please help resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think that your code is meant to say

```
elif not request.form.get("password") **!=** request.form.get("confirmation"):
```

However currently it says

```
elif not request.form.get("password") **==** request.form.get("confirmation"):
```

Therefore even when it matches it is still returning an apology